# Real Analysis: Is $\emptyset$ a open set in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm learning real analysis.

> A subset $G$ of $X$ is called open if for each $x \in G$ there is a
>   neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in G

My question is that is  $\emptyset$  a open set in $X$?

The set $\emptyset$ has no elements, so there is no neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $G$. Hence, it is not open set. However my intuitive tell me it should be a open set. What's wrong? Could anyone explain it? Thanks.

Comment: It is open, since the implication is trivially (vacuously) satisfied.

Comment: See [Why is predicate “all” as in all(SET) true if the SET is empty?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/202452/856)

Comment: Also, when you say "there is no neighborhood of $x$ [that] is contained in $G$", what do you mean by $x$?

Comment: The phrase "there is no neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $G$" is neither true nor false: instead it is a predicate whose domain is the empty set. It would yield a particular truth value if you plugged in an element of the empty set, but since there aren't any, you can't even do that!

Answer (score 3):

A subset of a metric space $X$ is either open or not open.   If $\emptyset$ were not open, there would be a point $x \in \emptyset$ such that there exists no neighborhood of $x$ contained in $\emptyset$.  However, by definition there are no points at all in $\emptyset$.  Hence, $\emptyset$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for any statement $P$, for every element of $\emptyset$, the statement $P$ is *vacuously true*.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said:

A subset G of X is called open if for each x∈G there is a neighborhood of x that is contained in G

If G is empty you can not choose a x that not satisfies  this. So G is open.

Comment: If G is empty you can not choose a x that  satisfies this. So G is not open.

Comment: @TengPeng I wanted put NOT

Comment: @Teng: Openness is not "there exists an $x$ in $G$ such that $x$ has a neighborhood contained in $G$".