# Quantification over the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is predicate “all” as in all(SET) true if the SET is empty?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty)

In don't quite understand this quantification over the empty set:

$\forall y \in \emptyset: Q(y)$

The book says that this is always TRUE regardless of the value of the predicate $Q(y)$, and it explain that this is because this quantification adds no predicate at all, and therefore can be considered the weakest predicate possible, which is TRUE.

I know that TRUE is the weakest predicate because $ $P$ \Rightarrow$ TRUE is TRUE for every $P$.
I don't see what is the relationship between this weakest predicate and the quantification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you see a quantification like ‘$\forall \phi x : \psi x$’, this is shorthand for ‘$\forall x : \phi x \to \psi x$’. Since ‘$x \in \emptyset$’ is false for all ‘$x$’, the antecedent of ‘$x \in \emptyset \to \psi x$’ will always be false. Thus, the entire conditional statement is always true.

Edit:
In the case of existential quantification, the statement ‘$\exists \phi x : \psi x$’ is shorthand for ‘$\exists x : \phi x \land \psi x$’, so in this case, the conjunction ‘$x \in \emptyset \land \psi x$’ will always be false.

Comment: Where can I find a little more explanation about those shorthands? because if becomes very clear when I know this shorthands. But I can't figure out how can I get those shorthands notations

Comment: The concept is discussed here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier

Answer (score 2):

A peculiar explanation.

Whatever $Q(y)$ may be, it is true that for all $y\in \emptyset$, the sentence $Q(y)$ is true. For the empty set is $\dots$ empty.  Every unicorn likes wine.

Answer (score 2):

Well if $\forall y \in \emptyset : Q(y)$ were false, we would be able to find some $y \in \emptyset$ such that $Q(y)$ were false. However, there are no $y \in \emptyset$. So $\forall y \in \emptyset : Q(y)$ should be true.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no members to the set, anything you say about a member can be considered *trivially* true. It's not really to say that there are actually members for which Q, but rather for all y, Q(y)--i.e. there are no circumstances where y and not Q(y).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the idea, but it confuses me when I compare this reasoning with the existencial quantifier over the empty set
$ \exists x \in \emptyset : P(x) $

I think this is TRUE because I'm quantifying over the empty set too.

Comment: You think it's true that there is an element of $\emptyset$ for which $P$ holds?  Which element would that be?

Comment: You're right but I'm still very confused sorry =(.