# Some member of an empty set

Tags: logic

Although you may feel my question is somehow strange,
please let me ask seriously whether the following 2 statements are true respectively.

Let S be the set of all positive integers less than 0.

Statement P1: For some member x of S, x > 0.

Statement P2: For some member x of S, x = 2 and x is not a prime number.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Symbolically the first statement is $\exists x\in S(x>0)$ or, if you prefer, $\exists x(x\in S\land x>0)$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, they are true.

Comment: @Emin No, they are not.

Comment: The "Related" list at the side of the page here gives a lot of things that aren't quite duplicates but basically answer this question: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/assumption-about-elements-of-the-empty-set) [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/202452/29966)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A statement of the form "for some member of a set $S$, [...]" is necessarily false if $S$ has no members.

On the other hand, statements of the form "for all members of $S$, [...]" are necessarily true. So you can transform statement P2 into a form which sounds equivalent:

"for all members $x$ of $S$, if $x = 2$ then $x$ is not a prime number"

but is in fact true.